# MongoIterable.forEach vs. Iterable.forEach

Tags: mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

`MongoIterable.forEach` requires a [`Block`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/Block.html) which is very similar to Java 8 [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).
They are similar enough to cause problems, for example, the following doesn't compile:

```
MongoIterable<Document> result = collection.find(...);
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

because the compiler can't decide between `Iterable.forEach( Consumer )`  and `MongoIterable.forEach( Block )`. Fixing this requires workarounds like explicitly typing the parameter:

```
Block<Document> printer = System.out::println;
result.forEach(printer);
```

or alternatively, treating `MongoIterable` as a plain `Stream`:

```
StreamSupport.stream(result.spliterator(), false).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Why is `MongoIterable.forEach` not defined using the `Consumer` interface, something like: `MongoIterable.forEach(Consumer<? super TResult> consumer)`? Even better - why have `forEach` in `MongoIterable` at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java driver still supports Java 6 as a target.  So while the attempts were made to make the 3.0 driver Java 8 and lambda friendly, we couldn't use actual Java 8 interfaces.

Comment: This explains why Consumer is not used, but I am still not clear as to why have MongoIterable.forEach in the first place. Is it to give non Java 8 users a Java 8 like experience ?

Comment: It was intended to make it more friendly.  The jury's still out if that goal was achieved or not.

Comment: It would have been nice to have a different name to avoid the name class, like `forEachMongo` (or maybe an even cooler name?). Luckily a simple type cast solves the issue.